# Text graphic - artistic play on repeated words

Tags: text, critique

I am trying to think of a cool way to visualize this quote from Fight Club:

> You know how they say 'you only hurt the ones you love?' Yeah, well
>   the inverse is also true.

So the way I'm interpreting this is with the following two sentences:

- You only hurt the ones you love.
- Only the ones you love hurt you.

Using these two sentences I'd like to create a visual that shows both sentences but doesn't repeat too many words. So I want to find some way to make both sentences clear with only minimal repetition.

My attempt is like this:

[image]

### Question

Is this graphic intuitive with my goal? I'm concerned that the 2nd sentence isn't so clear since you have to omit "hurt" in order for it to read correctly.  I'd also be keen to see if anyone has other ways to tackle this.

Comment: This is too subjective and opinion-based. For me, no. It does not work.

Comment: I kind of get what you are trying to say, but what you have written isn't grammatical and so it doesn't make any sense in English.  You could try this: "You only hurt yourself when you hurt those you love", or even shorter "Those you hurt, hurt you"" or something like that.

Comment: "Hurting those you love will hurt you", "It hurts to hurt those you love", etc . . .